# On Android how can I make a background app capture and edit the frame buffer (given root)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-ndk

To clarify I want to be able to grab a display update before it actually gets displayed, make changes to it, and then display the result. The last  two steps seems like they wouldn't be too difficult, but I'm completely lost as to how I would accomplish the first.

Comment: To get a better understanding of the rendering part of Android see Google IO video Butter or Worse - https://youtu.be/Q8m9sHdyXnE.